# video calling in iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, opentok, videochat, video-conferencing

I'm new to iPhone.I'm developing an application which contains video calling facility, For reference I have downloaded sample from
https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Basic-Tutorial

I have added OpenTok framework. I'm running it im simulator but the application crashes with error
Program received signal:SIGABRT.

It is not being able to establish connection

can any one suggest me how can i do this using other framework?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use a different framework because the one you have crashes in the simulator? Have you tried running this on a real device? Calls to camera API tend to crash on the simulator considering it isn't actually hooked up to any camera.

Comment: I tried it in device its crashing in device also

Comment: This sample app didn't crash for me. It also establishes connection with no issues. You might want to read the project description first to get it working.

Comment: i made changes now the app is not crashing but it is not able to call delegate methods and cant establish connection

Comment: When you run the app on the device, there should be a bunch of logs coming out on the console. Can you upload them to gist.github.com and comment with the link?

Answer (score 1):

Without any logs, I can only guess what the problem might be. It would be more helpful if you posted some logs.

1. Like 0x7ff... said, OpenTok needs a device to work properly because it needs the camera to be able to publish
2. invalid credentials should not be causing crashes, but you should still make sure your sessionId and token are valid. Keep in mind that tokens expire after 24 hours unless specified otherwise
3. Make sure you are deploying to a device that is [supported](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc#supported-devices)
4. If you are cloning from the basic tutorial, simply downloading the zip file will not work because the sdk is not downloaded with it. You would have to download the [OpenTok SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-webrtc) and place it in the appropriate folder.
   Alternatively, you can run `git clone --recursive https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Basic-Tutorial' in your terminal.

These are all the reasons I can think of